# Mostrar apenas dias de atraso positivos em consulta SQL?

Tags: sql-server, query

Estou fazendo uma consulta onde pretendo calcular a quantidade de dias de atraso em um vencimento, gostaria de mostrar apenas se existir dias de atraso, no momento estou mostrando dias que faltam para o vencimento, que deveria vim zero.

```html
Ex:
Data de vencimento
2015-04-20 00:00:00.000
2015-05-20 00:00:00.000
2015-05-20 00:00:00.000
2015-06-15 00:00:00.000

Resultado para a data de hoje:
0
-30
-30
-56
```

```html
select a.* 
, b.tipododocumento
, b.contacontabil
, d.nome 
, b.descricao
, a.formapagamentoA
, a.formapagamentoB
, a.data_inc
, a.data_alt
, a.letranota
, a.numeroparcela
,case a.statusregistro 
  when 'A' then 
    DATEDIFF (DAY, a.datavencimento,GETDATE() ) 
  when 'L' then
    0
  end AS diasatraso
 
from 
tb_recebimento a  
left outer join  tb_plano_contas b  on  a.controleplano = b.controleplano                     
left outer join   tb_cliente_fornecedor d   on  a.controlecliente = d.controlecliente         
Full Outer Join   tb_c_vendas c   on  c.controle = a.controlevenda                     
where a.statusregistro = 'A' 
and b.tipododocumento = 'D' 
and a.controleempresa = '1' 
order by a.datavencimento
```

Comment: O que está sendo mostrado e qual é o comportamento desejado?

Comment: Adicione na minha pergunta o resultado dos campos que preciso, quando a data é negativa é porque ainda não chegou na data de vencimento, após isso passa a ser positiva. quero mostra apenas os dias apos a data de vencimento

Comment: Venceu se a data do vencimento é menor que a data de hoje (ou uma data base tipo data último arquivo de baixa cnab do banco) , a subtracão das duas datas dá os dias em atraso , sem levar em conta feriados ou fim de semana , functions e exemplos a rodo na web acredite ...

Comment: @Motta, você não entendeu a minha pergunta!

Comment: @itasouza, eu não devo ter entendido mesmo , desculpe , de qualquer forma parece já ter sido sanada, []´s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece bem simples de resolver:

```
select * from (
    select a.* 
    , b.tipododocumento
    , b.contacontabil
    , d.nome 
    , b.descricao
    , a.formapagamentoA
    , a.formapagamentoB
    , a.data_inc
    , a.data_alt
    , a.letranota
    , a.numeroparcela
    ,case a.statusregistro 
      when 'A' then 
        DATEDIFF (DAY, a.datavencimento,GETDATE() ) 
      when 'L' then
        0
      end AS diasatraso

    from 
    tb_recebimento a  
    left outer join  tb_plano_contas b  on  a.controleplano = b.controleplano                     
    left outer join   tb_cliente_fornecedor d   on  a.controlecliente = d.controlecliente         
    Full Outer Join   tb_c_vendas c   on  c.controle = a.controlevenda                     
    where a.statusregistro = 'A' 
    and b.tipododocumento = 'D' 
    and a.controleempresa = '1'  
) tabela where tabela.diasatraso >= 0
order by tabela.datavencimento
```

Comment: Tive um erro:
Mensagem 1033, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 29
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @itasouza Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: eu já tinha testado assim:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Atualizei novamente.

Comment: The column 'descricao' was specified multiple times for 'tabela'.

Comment: Troque o `a.*` pela especificação das colunas. `descricao` aparece duas vezes, por isso o erro.

Comment: Deu certo!! agradeço!